# Differentiate Drag and Touch in cocos 2d iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hii
I have an issue in drag and touch an image. I have 3 images. Let it be left, right and middle. Initially middle image is shown in screen1. If i touch that image, it should open in a new screen(2). If i drag right side, it have to show right image in that screen itself. otherwise If i drag left side, it have to show left image in that screen. After that if i touched the left/right image it has to open that image in separate screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're implementing the three touches events (ccTouchesBegan, ccTouchesMoved, and ccTouchesEnded), you can set a global flag when ccTouchesMoved is fired.  This will indicate that a drag has occurred.  When ccTouchesEnded fires and that flag is not set, you can assume it is a simple tap.